# Reduce Code Duplication when Searching for values in XML with XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, dictionary, code-duplication

I am writing some code to parse an xml file of the following format (truncated for simplicity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ship name="Foo">
 <base_type>Foo</base_type>
 <GFX>fooGFX</GFX>
 ....
</ship>
```

I am using a dictionary consisting of key pairs of parameter and and xpath to value, and querying this to load all the values into various variables. However, I am noticing that there will be a massive amount of code duplication. In fact, for every value I wish to retrieve, I will have to write another line of almost identical looking code. Here is my code:

```
class Ship
{
    public Ship()
    {
        paths = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        //Define path to various elements
        paths.Add("name", "/ship/@name");
        paths.Add("base_type", "/ship/base_type");
        paths.Add("GFX", "/ship/GFX");
    }
    public void LoadFile(string filename)
    {// Loads the file and grabs the parameters
        doc.Load(filename);
        Name = doc.SelectSingleNode(paths["name"]).Value;
        Base_type = doc.SelectSingleNode(paths["base_type"]).Value;
        GFX = doc.SelectSingleNode(paths["GFX"]).Value;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> paths; //The XPaths to the various elements, define them in constructor
    public XmlDocument doc;
    public string Name;
    public string Base_type;
    public string GFX;
}
```

Notice the duplication here:

```
variable = doc.SelectSingleNode(paths["variable_name"]).value.
```

There are going to be many more variables, so this section will be massive.

Is there anyway to simplify this? If this was C++, I would probably try pointers, but I know they are not recommended for use in C#, so is there a similar way?

I would be looking for something that I could give a list of variable names and xpaths, and have the code pull out all the values and load them in the variable in some kind of loop or something. I want to use XPaths because I expect that the format of this file may change periodically.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I would also like to be able to modify this data and save it back. I am not adverse to saving an entire new tree if necessary, but it would be nice to modify the data in place if possible. I don't need a solution for the modification, but I just need to have this option open.

Comment: The last part -- saving the chamges back -- is conveniently done using the other main method of the XmlSerializer class -- Serialize().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One good way to achieve the population of the object is by using [XmlSerializer.Deserialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx).**

Something like this:

```
namespace TestSerialization
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    public class TestSerialization
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string theXml =
@"<ship name='Foo'>
 <base_type>Foo</base_type>
 <GFX>fooGFX</GFX>
</ship>";
            Ship s = Ship.Create(theXml);

            // Write out the properties of the object.
            Console.Write(s.Name + "\t" + s.GFX);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("ship")]
    public class Ship
    {
        public Ship() { }

        public static Ship Create(string xmlText)
        {
            // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer specifying type.
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Ship));

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlText);

            XmlReader xreader = new XmlTextReader(sr);

            // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
            return (Ship)serializer.Deserialize(xreader);
        }

        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name;

        [XmlElement("base_type")]
        public string Base_type;

        public string GFX;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: The OP has added an additional question:

> I would also like to be able to modify this data and save it back. I
>   am not adverse to saving an entire new tree if necessary

**Just use the `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` method**.

Here is a typical example of using it:

```
  // Create an XmlTextWriter using a FileStream.
  Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
  XmlWriter writer = 
  new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.Unicode);
  // Serialize using the XmlTextWriter.
  serializer.Serialize(writer, yourObject);
  writer.Close();
```

Comment: Could you show me how this would function in the context of my xml file?

Comment: @Biosci3c: Yes, I updated my answer with a complete solution.

Comment: @ssg, Yes, I believe so. This requires only minimal coding, is very easy to use and very powerful.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I seriously think I am going to go this route, as it seems sooooo much easier than parsing like mad. One thing though, the bracketed [XmlRoot("ship")] syntax baffles me, as I have never seen it before. Could you possibly explain this a little (i.e. is it a template, a class, etc)? Thanks.

Comment: @Biosci3c: You are welcome. And yes, please, let me know how this worked in practice.

Comment: Sorry edited comment. Could you explain the bracketed [xmlroot("ship")] terminology to me, as I have never seen it before.

Comment: You ROCK!!! This is such an amazing method. I love it when things are so simple. Big accept for you. I seem to be able to access elements without having to write much code for each element. Haven't tried writing to xml yet, but I'm sure it will be nice and simple. This solves a big issue for me, namely, having a class representation of the "ship" and an xml representation. Now I can edit both at once. Very Nice! Thanks again.

Comment: @Biosci3c: You are welcome. The C# attribute `[XmlRoot("ship")]` is specifying that the top element of the serialized XML representation of the object must have the name of `"ship"`. You may read more about the different serialization attributtes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok, I've run into one issue. Some of the elements are optional (i.e. a "License" element), and I need a way to have it ignore this and set the corresponding variable as Null. Also, I need to have it not write the elements for any null variables.

Comment: @Biosci3c: If the element has no text-node child, the corresponding property's value will be empty string or null (have to check). You don't care if the serialization creates an empty element either -- because of this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10680/discussion-between-biosci3c-and-dimitre-novatchev)

Comment: Resolved, was my mistake. Was a file not found error, not a "missing element" error. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound weird to you, but if you're going for a massive amount of data, then personally, I would go for an auto-generated code solution.

Meaning: Map all your XML names -> to their XPath expressions -> to display names, and have something that will auto-generate a data class for you.

For example:

Let's say the input file is in CSV format (or tab delimited, etc):

**DisplayName,XMLField,XPathExpr**

Name,name,/ship/@name

Base_type,base_type,/ship/base_type

GFX,GFX,/ship/GFX

Now you'll need some process that will auto-generate code out of it. For this you can develop a C# utility program, use some scripting language like Perl, or even create some XSL translation.

The end result would look something like:

```
class AutoGeneratedShipData
{
    public AutoGeneratedShipData(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        // Code initialization like in your sample
    }

    public string Name ...
    public string Base_type ...
    public string GFX ...
}
```

You can continue and add serialization, INotifyPropertyChanged support, and other adornments you might see fit.

**A different approach**

Would be to use reflection in order to load the data into properties, but for this you will need to manually create a property for each data member as well as the data mapping.

Here's an example:

```
LoadData(xmlDoc, "Name", "/ship/@name");
LoadData(xmlDoc, "Base_type", "/ship/base_type");
LoadData(xmlDoc, "GFX", "/ship/GFX");
```

Where `LoadData()` would be something like:

```
private void LoadData(XmlDocument xmlDoc, Dictionary<string, string> propertyNameToXPathMap)
{
    foreach ( PropertyInfo pi in this.GetType().GetProperties() )
    {
        // Is the property mapped to an xpath?
        if ( propertyNameToXPathMap.ContainsKey(pi.Name) )
        {
            string sPathExpression = propertyNameToXPathMap[pi.Name];

            // Extract the Property's value from XML based on the xpath expr.
            string value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(sPathExpression).Value;

            // Set this object's property's value
            pi.SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that I'm ignoring your `paths` dictionary because I don't see any special role for it.

Comment: Interesting idea. Hmm, so you are suggesting that I write a program to write the code automatically so that I can change it when neccesary. So you are saying there is no way to store a list of references to variables and xpaths and have it retrieve this as I want?

Comment: Yup, what ever feels comfortable. I added more code in case you'd like to use reflection on the `Ship` class itself. Personally, however, I would still encapsulate the `Ship`'s state in a data class, that is easy to serialize, pass via a Communication Layer, etc.

Comment: Whoa.. your comment completely changed.. I didn't say that's impossible. I also added an example on how to do it with reflection. If you have a closed XML for each class, then you can also generate an XSD schema for it and auto-generate a class out of that schema with Xsd2Code for example.

Comment: I would love to go the schema route, but I don't have VS 2010, only the express edition. Any suggestions on how to easily make a schema? Also, I want to add that I need to be able to modify the tree and save it back later. I'll update the question.

Comment: You can use Xsd2Code from command line in a pre-build step. Add flags for creating Xml serialization and you'll have auto-generated Serialize() / Deserialize() methods (both from/to string and from/to file).

Comment: And there are tools that will reverse engineer your XML data and build an XSD schema out of it. E.g. IntelliJ Idea environment (once you get the hand of it :)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to define your own [custom attribute type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for mapping a property to an XPath selector, define automatic properties for your variables that need to be mapped to an XPath selector, and decorate these using your custom attribute. For example:

```
[MapTo("/ship/@name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[MapTo("/ship/base_type")]
public string BaseType { get; set; }
```

Then after loading your XML document, write a loop that uses reflection to iterate through each of these properties and set their value based on their associated XPath selector. For example, assuming the custom attribute is declared this way:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MapToAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string XPathSelector { get; private set; }

    public MapToAttribute(string xPathSelector)
    {
        XPathSelector = xPathSelector;
    }
}
```

Then your loop that performs the mapping, assuming it's somewhere inside an instance method in the class holding your mapped properties (if not, replace `this` to the target object), would be like this:

```
foreach (var property in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var mapToAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MapToAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as MapToAttribute;
    if (mapToAttribute != null)
    {
        property.SetValue(this, doc.SelectSingleNode(mapToAttribute.XPathSelector).Value);
    }
}
```